# Saving a DynamicMethod to disk

Tags: .net, cil, dynamicmethod

I have inherited code that uses DynamicMethod to generate methods at runtime. I also need to modify some of the code that is being generated.

Since I am a n00b at MSIL, I would love to be able to load the generated code up in Reflector and ensure that the code does what I pray that it does ;)

Only, I can't figure out how to serialize the "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly" to disk. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you want to load the method in Reflector or dotPeek, you need to create an actual assembly. To do this, [use `MethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ssa260d.aspx#93034656-1c6c-4154-b917-d57c78d61607) instead of `DynamicMethod`. Most of the usage of them should be the same.

Comment: Sorry to keep this open for so long. I wanted to wait until I could implement this before I accepted, but of course I'm working on another project now! Still, this seems like the only real answer, so when I get back to working on this, I'll know what to do.

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
  var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("SomeName");
  var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, @"c:");
  var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Name +  ".dll");

  TypeBuilder builder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Test", TypeAttributes.Public);
  var methodBuilder = builder.DefineMethod("DynamicCreate", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(T), new[] { typeof(IDataRecord) }); 
  /* this line is a replacement for your  new DynamicMethod(....)  line of code

  /* GENERATE YOUR IL CODE HERE */

  var t = builder.CreateType();
  assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
```